# How to retrieve default args in python callable

Tags: airflow

I need to be able to access default_args defined as part of DAG definition in a Python Operator, python_callable. Maybe it's my unfamiliartiy with python or airflow in general, but could someone guide on how to achieve this.

Following is a code sample of what am trying to achieve

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': 'xyz@xyz.com',
    'email_on_failure': 'xyz@xyz.com',
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 5, 15, 23, 20),
    'end_date': datetime(2017, 5, 16, 23, 45),
    'touchfile_path': '/user/myname/touchfiles/',
}

dag = DAG(
    'test',
    default_args=default_args,
    template_searchpath=['/Users/myname/Desktop/utils/airflow/resources'],
    user_defined_macros=dict(SCHEMA_NAME='abc'),
    #schedule_interval='*/2 * * * * ')
    schedule_interval='@once')

def webhdfs_touchfile_create(ds, *args, **kwargs):
    web_hdfs_hook = WebHDFSHook('webhdfs_default')
    client = web_hdfs_hook.get_conn()
    client.write("/user/myname/airflow_hdfs","stringToWrite")
    pp.pprint(kwargs)

task1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='task1',
    provide_context=True, #enabling this would allow to pass arguments automatically to your callable function
    python_callable=webhdfs_touchfile_create,
    templates_dict={'attr1': {{ default_args['touchfile_path'] }}},
    dag=dag)
```

Since the template_dict for PythonOperator is the only attribute which jinja templating works, how can i retrieve the '**touchfile_path**' paramter in there?

Comment: Does the touchfile_path included in default_args?

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 mechanisms for passing variables in Airflow:

- (1) Jinja templating
- (2) Specialized operator properties

Using (1) approach variables can be passed via `user_defined_macros` property on the *DAG* level.
Using (2) approach you should take a look on specific *operator* properties.

Note, that some operator properties are processed by Jinja and you can use template syntax.

Here is a working example:

```
from datetime import timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(2),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'custom_key1': 'custom_value1',
    'custom_key2': 'custom_value2'
}

dag = DAG(
    'tutorial',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1),
    user_defined_macros=default_args ,
)

bash_command = """
    echo "access via DAG's user_defined_macros = {{ custom_key1 }}"
    echo "access via Operator's params = {{ params.custom_key2 }}"
"""

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_in_bash_op',
    bash_command=bash_command,
    params=default_args,
    dag=dag,
)

def myfunc(**context):
    print(context['templates_dict']['custom_key1'])
    print(context['templates_dict']['custom_key2'])


t2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_in_python_op',
    python_callable=myfunc, 
    templates_dict=default_args,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)

templates_dict={
    'custom_key1': '{{ custom_key1 }}',
    'custom_key2': '{{ custom_key2 }}'
}

t3 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_in_python_op_2',
    python_callable=myfunc, 
    templates_dict=templates_dict,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)

t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

**Addition based on comments**

Ability of using variables is fully depends on **Operator**.

In (2) approach typically there are specialized properties for passing information like:

- bash_command in BashOperator,
- op_kwargs in PythonOperator,
- sql in BigQueryOperator

For using approach (1) such properties should be rendered using jinja in Operator code (they are marked as `templated` in documentation).
For instance, properties above are `templated` properties.

In every place where [Airflow Macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros.html) 
can be used, user variables (defined via `user_defined_macros`) can be also used.

Comment: Yes, this looks pretty good. Is user_defined_macros at the dag level available in a Python operator?

Comment: Yes, take a look on t3 task in the example above.

You can render jinja variables (defined via user_defined_macros) in     'templates_dict', 'op_args', 'op_kwargs' properties.

Comment: @IIya Good suggestions. However, aren't default arguments meant for defining at the DAG level only and all the tasks under that DAG should inherit them? If we are having to explicitly pass the default arguments to each task (whether via `templates_dict` or `params`), the what's the point of `default_args`? Shouldn't there be an easier way of accessing the default args within a task?

Answer (score 5):

In Airflow 2.0, TaskFlow means a "Python callable" is sometimes just a function annotated with @task. In this case, you can retrieve the default args from the context:

```
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context

    @task
    def my_task():
        context = get_current_context()
        email_on_failure = context["dag"].default_args["email_on_failure"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since they are defined in the same file at the same level you can do like:

```py
def webhdfs_touchfile_create(ds, *args, **kwargs):
    web_hdfs_hook = WebHDFSHook('webhdfs_default')
    client = web_hdfs_hook.get_conn()
    client.write("/user/myname/airflow_hdfs","stringToWrite")
    pp.pprint(kwargs) 
    pp.pprint(default_args['touchfile_path'])
```

Comment: Anyone got any thoughts on whether this is a good idea or not?

Comment: I like this solution. It's simple and doesn't rely on airflow's infrastructure, just good ol' python. It's certainly the easiest to implement and that's a big + for me

Answer (score 0):

The default args should be available in *args. Have you tried accessing `touchfile_path` from there?